# Is the intrinsic object creation order mentioned by the ECMAScript Specification defined somewhere?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016, ecmascript-next, ecma

This is a question regarding the latest revision of ECMA-262. At https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-createintrinsics it says

> The creation of the intrinsics and their properties must be ordered to avoid any dependencies upon objects that have not yet been created.

Is there somewhere a specific order defined or do implementers have to figure this out on their own?

I'm asking because that would be nice to have and would be a good fit for the Appendix. But maybe I missed it somehow.

Thanks for reading and warm regards!

Comment: _"The abstract operation` CreateIntrinsics`..."_ -> [7 Abstract Operations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-operations): _"These operations are not a part of the ECMAScript language; they are defined here solely to aid the specification of the semantics of the ECMAScript language."_

Comment: I see what you mean, but generally speaking, giving implementers some information about order would also aid the specification of semantics. It's not necessary as part of the specification, I get that, but it would be nice to have ;) Thanks for your comment and answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no specific order. It is not observable by user code, so it does not matter at all.

Implementers have to decide this on their own. There are many possible orders. You even may create objects and their properties separate from each other, as there are circular references (e.g. between a `.prototype` and its `.constructor`, or between `Function` and `Object`).

Answer (score 0):

That section contains this text:

> The value of each field is a new object value fully and recursively populated with property values as defined by the specification of each object in clauses 19 through 28.

The order of the clauses is the order of the definitions.

For example, first the [global object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-global-object) is defined, and then [JS objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-objects) are defined, [functions](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-objects) are defined, other things like [Errors](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-error-objects) and various [Error subclasses](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-aggregate-error-objects) are defined, and so on.

Comment: I thought that at first too, but for example %AggregateError.prototype% has a [[Prototype]] internal slot with the value %Error.prototype%. However %AggregateError% would be created before %Error.prototype%, so %Error.prototype% doesn't exist at the time of %AggregateError% creation, except one preallocates some stuff but that's not optimal.

Comment: Creating intrinsic objects in the order they appear in the specification might work. So 'Fundamental Objects' first, after that objects from the 'Numbers and Dates' section, etc.. Oh and thanks for the answer!

Comment: You're completely right, I skipped over that text [in your link](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-createintrinsics), it's the order of clauses that matters.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your edited answer! I will try it out and see if it works out, when it does I will accept this answer :)

Comment: "*The order of the clauses is the order of the definitions.*" - I don't see anything in the spec to substantiate that. Sure, it refers to the spec sections where the all the objects are described, but that doesn't imply an order to me.

Comment: That's what I understood from *The creation of the intrinsics and their properties must be ordered to avoid any dependencies upon objects that have not yet been created.*, since it's not [Table 8](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-well-known-intrinsic-objects). Maybe I'm wrong, but it's at least referring to *some* order, and I can't see any other meaning of the reference.

Comment: I'm now convinced that it wouldn't be possible to specify an order since it's heavily implementation dependent. If intrinsics are allocated one at a time there will be problems with circular dependencies, otherwise probably not since it's possible to  reference everything in memory even before object creation. So depending on the methods chosen the necessary ordering will change, or there might not be any need for ordering (not sure on that yet).

Comment: I think the sentence from the spec I quoted in my question is quite misleading. My understanding is that implementations can choose the way in which intrinsics are created quite freely, so saying that intrinsic creation MUST be ordered doesn't make sense, because the spec can't possibly know that.